# column size vs. key length: shouldn't they be the same?

Tags: mysql, explain

So i have an (unique) index on a `char(5)` column and when I do `EXPLAIN` on a query using it it says key_len is 15. why wouldn't it be 5?

Comment: Have you any other indexes on this table?

Comment: I'd guess the key is composed of the string field itself, pointer to the table and maybe some other metadata (considering there 10 bytes left, while I expect the pointer to be a power of two and probably 8) ?

Comment: @zavg = It's just the PRIMARY KEY and the UNIQUE INDEX and that's it. Should the key_len be equal to the length of all the keys, be they foreign or primary?

Comment: What database engine? InnoDB/MyISAM/... ?

Comment: Show us table description, query and `EXPLAIN` results